# Current Universal time in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, utc

How can I get the current time as Universal time in classic asp. I know how to get in C# and I am getting the universal time in c# with following line  ((DateTime.Now).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("s") and this code gives me time like this 2012-07-09T10:29:49

But I want to know the equivalent in classic asp. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can without converting it yourself using DATE_ADD or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [u229.no](http://www.u229.no/stuff/snippets/UTC.asp), there isn't any built-in way in VBScript to convert to UTC.

Take a look at the code the author provided below which uses JScript, and how you can call this from VBScript.

The GetServerGMT routine will return something like: Wed, 01 Feb 2006 15:21:59 UTC.

```
Function GetServerGMT()

    // Use JScript to get the current GMT time stamp and store it in Session("ServerGMT")
    Server.Execute "GetServerGMT.asp"
    GetServerGMT = Session("ServerGMT")

End Function
```

And this is how the GetServerGMT.asp file with the jscript code looks like:

```
<%@language="jscript"%>
<%
    var od = new Date();
    var nd = od.toUTCString();
    Session("ServerGMT") = nd;
%>
```

There are [other jscript methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) that you can use as well.

Comment: var nd = od.`toGMTString()`; is deprecated, use `toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: Hmmm, a bit of an odd answer. you said "No, there is no way to do it..." and then you followed with an explanation for how to do it. ??  (ps: JScript is a real ASP-Classic language)

Comment: @Cheeso Since VBScript and JScript both shipped with ASP Classic, you're right. However, if you'd notice, what I provided was verbatim the reference. Also, with the more common IDE DreamWeaver, new .asp pages are defaulted to VBScript. So I assumed the OP was using VBScript.

Comment: @Ian, not sure what you mean by "What I provided was verbatim the reference." Maybe you mean you are simply quoting someone else. But that's not a good excuse for repeating incorrect or misleading information. My point is that your answer considered in its entirety is inconsistent. Clearly the answer is not "No" as your initial sentence now states. In fact *there is a way to do it*, and you pointed it out. There is a requirement that  "you must use jscript", but that is well within the lines of mainstream ASP Classic. I upvoted your answer; I'm just pointing out that it's a little confusing.

Comment: Next solution is a lot cleaner, no extra invocation, no passing state via Session

Answer (score 12):

As [Ian pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398454/48082) you can generate a UTC time via Javascript.

You specified "ASP Classic" which of course includes Javascript as a language (Actually JScript, based on ECMAScript v3), so there's one answer for you:  Call `(new Date()).toUTCString()`.

If by chance you prefer to code your pages in mostly VBScript, you can mix in just a little JScript to get it done.  You don't need to resort to `Server.Execute` or Sessions to make that happen.

This works for me:

```
<%@ language="VBScript" %>
<script language='JScript' runat='server'>
  function jsGetUTCTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.toUTCString();
  }
</script>
<script language='VBScript' runat='server'>
Function getUTCTime()
    ' Use JScript to get the current GMT time stamp
    getUTCTime = jsGetUTCTime()
End Function
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mix</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h2>The time is:</h2>
   <%= getUTCTime() %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't include "JavaScript" as a language it includes JScript which was based on ECMAScript v3. The fact Microsoft allows you to tag it as "JavaScript" is just an alias and a really poor decision on their part. If you use `language="JScript"` it works as well. The use of "JavaScript" in this answer will be confusing to those not aware of JScript's history.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is

```
%>
 <script runat="server" language="javascript">
     function getTimezoneOffset() {             
         return (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()
     }
</script>
<%
Function nowUtc()
   nowUtc=DateAdd("n",getTimezoneOffset(),Now)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on above code

```
<%@ language="VBScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <script language='Javascript' runat='server'>

            // good for creating cookie timestamps that match RFC 1123
            function jsGetFutureTimeGMT(minutes) {
                var d = new Date();
                var future = new Date();
                future.setTime(d.getTime() + (minutes*60000));
                var utcString = future.toUTCString();
                var tz = utcString.indexOf("UTC");
                if (tz > 0) {
                    utcString = utcString.substring(0, tz) + "GMT";
                }
                return utcString;
            }
        </script>

        <title>ASP Classic RFC 1123 compliant GMT timestamp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>ASP Classic RFC 1123 compliant GMT timestamp</h2>
    <pre>
     The VBS time right now is: <%= Now() %>
     The time in 10 minutes is: <%= jsGetFutureTimeGMT(10) %>
    </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is connected to a database, you can probably get a timestamp from the database with a simple fast query. For example, in MySQL it's: `SELECT unix_timestamp()`.

This will give you a Unix Timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch).  From there convert into whatever format you like.