# asp classic need to get current time in EST

Tags: asp.net, datetime, time, asp-classic

I Need to get  the current  Eastern time zone.
I am using asp classic. I tried alot but I did not got the solution.
Any one can help me.
I am using 
    Now()

to get the current value in vb classic but i need current time in Eastern time zone.

Comment: Get UTC time -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11441116/246342 Add the offset (remembering some places will use daylight savings in the summer)

Comment: If you want the whole application to use EST and there is no other applications on the server that could be affected change the time-zone in the regional settings on the Windows Server. Remember Classic ASP gets it's date/time information from the regional settings of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that converting to UTC time is the way to go, precisely *because* then you get to deal with the headaches of daylight savings time. Instead, figure out what time zone the server is set to, figure out what the offset is from that to Eastern time, and then instead of just `Now`, use `DateAdd('h',3,Now)`. (Naturally, replace 3 with the correct number if the server is not on the west coast.)

Comment: This makes the code dependent on the server time zone. Getting UTC and converting to EST/EDT means if someone changes the server time zone (or the code moves to another server or whatever) it won't affect the calculation. I think that's why Alex K suggested UTC in the first place. There's also an assumption that the server and whatever area of EST you're targeting celebrate DST at the same time and in the same way. That's going to be true with either solution but if you use UTC you have to explicitly deal with it instead of depending on the vageries of server vs. target locale time.

Comment: @Craig, that's seriously premature optimization. In reality, the likelihood of a server changing time zones is effectively zero, and if you have to change servers, you're gonna have to make fixes to the code, no matter what.

Comment: It's fairly trivial to change the time zone on the server. In a shared hosting environment or even in an environment where you're not the only person who has the ability and authority to do it, coding defensively is a good idea. And even in a co-located or dedicated environment it's not unusual to upgrade hardware and move sites. If I can limit how much of my code I have to revisit on a simple hardware or OS upgrade by doing something as easy as managing time zones with fewer assumptions, I wouldn't call that premature at all. Regardless, either solution will work. Just giving options.

Answer (score 0):

Alex K has the right answer, which he put in the form of a comment. Here it is in the form of an answer:

Get UTC time -> [stackoverflow.com/a/11441116/246342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441116/246342) Add the offset (remembering some places will use daylight savings in the summer)

For my apps I try to store all times as UTC to avoid this problem. For some date/time calcs I can get by with the local time zone of the server, such as when I just need to know elapsed time. So then I'm just careful to make sure the server time zone is what I expect in case I ever need to display it. For example, our marketing dept doesn't think having our special offers expire at "midnight UTC" is very user-friendly, so we just say "midnight Central Time" and let people convert in their heads to their local time. Internally I can compare Now to the expiration date of the offer and it works fine.