# Getting curent time of specific time zone in classical asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, timezone, jscript

Here goes the problem:

I have a requirement that an (classical)asp application should display different content at specific EST(Eastern Time) duration. The clients can arrive from any timezone, but the server should take only EST time into consideration.

I am sorry for my ignorance, but I am from ASP.Net background and have no idea of doing this in classical asp.

This [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398084/current-universal-time-in-classic-asp) guided me to get UTC, but I still don't know how to convert it to EST.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The canonical way is to convert the date to UTC, then add the offset for your destination timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is in EST then not an issue, otherwise you'll need to compensate for it.

```
mytime = now()
myadjtime = DateAdd("h", 3, mytime)
```

will add 3 hours to the current time

```
<%
mytime = now()
response.write hour(mytime)

if hour(mytime) >=12 then
response.write "It's noon or later"
end if
%>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can check http://worldclockapi.com web site. You can take current time as timezone..

example: http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now 
if you go to above address you can see EST current date, time and other data..

example: http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now
if you go to above address, you can see PST current date, time and other data...

and you can use XMLHTTP for getting data from external site.

`

```
 private Function GETHTTP(adres)

 Set StrHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )
 StrHTTP.Open "GET" , adres, false
 StrHTTP.sEnd
 GETHTTP = StrHTTP.Responsetext
 Set StrHTTP = Nothing

End Function

 full_data= GETHTTP("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now")
```

`

after you use split code by comma:

`parts=split(full_data,",")
    response.write parts(1)`